# How to get method name from VariableDeclarationStatement

Tags: java, variables, declaration, eclipse-plugin

i have a variable of type VariableDeclarationStatement. I want to get the name of the method from this variable . How can i do that?Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the code in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg17244.html) and use an [`VariableDeclarationFragment`](http://www.jdocs.com/eclipse/3.1/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/VariableDeclarationFragment.html):

```
    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node)
    {
        System.out.println("Visiting variable declaration statement.");
        for(int i = 0; i < node.fragments().size(); ++i)
        {
            VariableDeclarationFragment frag = (VariableDeclarationFragment)node.fragments().get(i);
            System.out.println("Fragment: " + node.getType() + " " + frag.getName());
        }

        System.out.println("");        
        return true;
    }
```

To get the method in which this (variable) is defined, I would use a visitor of the `CompilationUnit`, looking for that `VariableDeclarationFragment` while memorizing the `IMethod` I am currently parsing:

```
        IJavaElement element = delta.getElement();

        if(element.getElementType() != IJavaElement.COMPILATION_UNIT)
            return;

        ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = (ICompilationUnit)element;

        try
        {

            IType type = compilationUnit.findPrimaryType();
            IMethod[] methods = type.getMethods();
            for(IMethod method : methods)
            {                
                ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);                
                parser.setSource(compilationUnit);
                parser.setSourceRange(method.getSourceRange().getOffset(), method.getSourceRange().getLength());
                //parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_CLASS_BODY_DECLARATIONS);
                //parser.setSource(method.getSource().toCharArray());
                //parser.setProject(method.getJavaProject());                
                parser.setResolveBindings(true);
                CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
                cu.accept(new ASTMethodVisitor());

                // If the visitor visit the right VariableDeclarationFragment,
                // then the right IMethod is the current 'method' variable

            }                        
        }
        catch(JavaModelException e)
        {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: but that will give the variable name and its type. I want the method name too in which it is declared

Comment: @Nishan: just added the Visitor strategy to find the `IMethod` in which a `VariableDeclarationStatement` is defined.

Comment: i didnt get it.Any link oe example please

Comment: @Nishan: do you have a `CompilationUnit` instance? If yes, the thread I mentioned is a good example. If not, please edit your question and add the code you have to get a `VariableDeclarationStatement`. From that, I will be able to find a more relevant example.